# I want to reinstall Windows Defender

Tags: windows-10

I deactivated Windows Defender because I had free Kaspersky from my Bank but now I want to reinstall it as bank is now ceasing to use Kaspersky.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you list the steps you've already taken to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you deactivate Windows Defender specifically?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/17464/windows-defender-help-protect-computer) website:

- Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Update & Security.
- Select Windows Defender, then turn Real-time protection on or off.

Comment: It's worth noting that it may take several tries to actually get this to stick (Windows automatically turns off Defender if it thinks there's another AV product installed, and some AV products aren't quite as thorough as they should be when uninstalling).